# How to add fadeIn animation to a list when doing unshift in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I've a form where  the user can post an update and on successful submission to the server, I want to push that item to a list below it. I know how to do it in Jquery and vanilla js but have no idea where to even start in Angular 4. Hope someone could help me.

Component File

```
<form (ngSubmit)="postStatus()">
  <ion-item>

        <ion-label>Post Update</ion-label>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="update" name="update"></ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
<ion-grid>
<ion-row>
<ion-col col-6>
  <button item-right ion-button color="secondary" small type="submit" block>Submit</button>
</ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-grid>

</form>


<ion-content>
<ion-card *ngFor="let p of posts">

  <ion-item>
    <h2 (click)="pushPage(p)">{{ p.user.name }}</h2>
    <p>{{p.created_at  }}</p>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-card-content>
    <p>{{ p.content }}</p>
  </ion-card-content>

</ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Typescript

```
  postStatus(){

    this.httpService.post(this.config.apiUrl+"status",{
      update: this.update
    }).map(
      data => data.json()
    ).subscribe(

      data => {
       this.posts.unshift({
         content:data.content,
         user:data.user,
         created_at:data.created_at,
       });
      },

      error => {
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Error!',
            subTitle: 'Some error occurred. Please try again',
            buttons: ['OK']
          });
          alert.present()
      });

  }
```

Comment: Have you found a solution ?